# HTML css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have index page and service page in html. On index page and service page there is different side menu. But both are for the services I provide .

So what I want to do is that the menu on index page when one of the menu is clicked first it shows some content related to that service on the same page and then it has a link read more.When a user clicks on read more link I want  to redirect to the service page and on the service the content related to the link clicked on index page menu to be displayed and that to in iframe which I am using in service page

```
<div id="service_section">
  <h2>Services</h2>
   <ul class="menu">
    <li tabindex="1">
     <span class="title">Financial Services</span>
     <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.
        <a href="services.html" target="myframe" onclick="openpages()">Read More</a>
     </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have tried so far. Voting to close as in its current state this question is too broad.

Comment: i will send you the coding of both the menus used

Comment: <div id="service_section">
        <h2>Services</h2>
      <ul class="menu">
    <li tabindex="1">
      <span class="title">Financial Services</span> 
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.<a href="services.html" target="myframe"  onclick="openpages()">Read More</a></div>
    </li>
 </ul>

Comment: its the menu used on index page

Comment: <div id="menu">
<h2>Our Bouquet Of Services</h2>
<nav>
  <ul class="mcd-menu">
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:loadintoIframe('myframe', 'index.html')">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <strong>Company Incorporation in India</strong>
     <small></small>
    </a>
   </li>

Comment: second one is the menu used on service page

Comment: are you getting my problem ?

Comment: @priyankajain please edit the body of your question, instead of posting code in comments. Use this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for help with how to post code.

Comment: i can direct that click on link of index page simply to service page ..but i want that particular link content to be displayed and that to in iframe of service page

Answer (score -1):

I understood a bit of your question.
You have to do.  Find the 'read more' in your page.
You can do it by copying and pasting your code in simple text editor likes notepad. Then press ctrl+F
Type 'read more'. You will find something like this

```
<a href="http://READMOREPAGELINK.html" > Read more </a>
```

Just change the page link to your desired page link.

Comment: no i have iframe in service page on index page i have menu which has read more link

Comment: I know that what you wanna do. You are using website templates and templates have only front page( index page) first you shoud have create another page where user will go wheb they click on read more link then place this page's link on service.html page

Comment: i have already created four pages now i just want to do is linking between pages

Comment: is there any way to send the design of page which ii have created

Comment: check your mail i have send you images of my webpage